# Autofill vue file

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur

I would like to know if there's any shorthand to fill the empty vue file with all three tags: template, script and style with proper default content.

As a comparison, at least, VS Code allows to autofill an html file with all default required tags/codes on `! + Enter`. I want to know if there's something alike in VS Code or Vetur extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've personally never used it but [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sdras.vue-vscode-snippets) seems to do what you're looking for. There seems to be a lot of different configuration options as well.

Comment: Glad it worked! It looked like a nice plugin